# vbs sql help with msaccess

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript

error msg: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,username,password, AllowSecureLogin  FROM Staff WHERE 1"

    Dim cmd
    Set cmd                  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn

    With cmd
        .CommandText         = strSQL
        .CommandType         = adCmdText        
    End With
```

i am no vb/ms access expert please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the following fields is NOT in your `Staff` table:

- `id`
- `firstname`
- `lastname`
- `username`
- `password`
- `AllowSecureLogin`

If all of those fields should be there I would double-check that there's not a spelling mistake or typo.  Also, `PASSWORD` is a [Jet reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).  You'll need to enclose it in square brackets in your query:

```
"SELECT id,firstname,lastname,username,[password],AllowSecureLogin FROM Staff"
```

Also, your `WHERE` clause is unnecessary because `1` will always evaluate to `True`.  Unless, of course, that what you really mean is `WHERE id = 1`.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Jet assumes that anything that looks like a field name but that does not correspond to an existing field is an implied parameter that the user expects to be filled in at runtime.  This is true regardless of where the "missing" field appears within the Query (the SELECT clause, the WHERE clause, ORDER BY,..., anywhere).  I personally get this error most often when I've written an UPDATE or INSERT query in VBA and have forgotten to enclose string literals in quotes.

Comment: you were actually i was building a login form from existing asp file i.e. and i didn't know that AllowSecureLogin was not there thanks, and i did actually meant WHERE 1=1 the reason for that is unexplainable. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is wrong.

I think you are trying to get the records where ID=1.
If my assumptions is correct change the SQL to(the where clause should be WHERE id = 1):

```
strSQL = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,username,password, AllowSecureLogin FROM Staff WHERE id = 1"
```